# How to remove HTML Entities &#8203 and empty <p></p> tag from SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have been working on SharePoint as a Frond End Designer.
When I edit any content page or Update content from **page edit option** that time some unknown HTML entities like **&#8203** and some empty **p tag** are inserted by default editor.

So my question is that How to remove those without disturbing any client site script.

See the screen cast of entites

[image]

I tried some JavaScript and jQuery code but default functions were disturbed like form validation.

Applied code for removing HTML entities.

```
var abc =  document.getElementById("contentBox").innerHTML;
    var a = String(abc).replace(/\u200B/g,'');
    document.getElementById("contentBox").innerHTML = a;
```

Comment: include what you have tried in OP

Comment: Added the code in question

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("divider-20").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Try reading this: http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Removing-8203-in-RichTextHTML-field-Sharepoint